# Python select specific item of JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a Python response, and some items of response have a key that others don't have.
Example JSON

```
"Order": [
    {
        "ID": "xxxxxx",
        "WNumber": "xxxxxxx",
        "Type": "xxxxxxx",
        "ServiceType": "xxxxxxxx",
        "Status": "xxxxxx",
        "StatusReason": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Priority": "xxxxxxxx",
        "Owner": "xxxxxxxx",
        "ContactID": "xxxxxxx",
        "AssetID": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "AccountID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    },
    {
        "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "WNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Type": "xxxxxxxx",
        "Status": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "StatusReason": "xxxxxxxx",
        "Priority": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Owner": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ContactID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "AssetID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "AccountID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "CaseID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        
    }
]
}
```

How can I extract from response the only item that have the key "CaseID" in the body?

Thanks
Best

Comment: you can use `in` operator like this `if 'CaseID' in json_data:` or you can use list comprehension to filter the data `[x for x in orders if 'CaseID' in x]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the one line solution for your problem. 
Use `in` to check occurence of CaseID in keys of dictionary using `dict.keys()`

```
result = [r for r in response["Order"] if "CaseID" in r.keys()]
print(result)

>>    [{'ID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'WNumber': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'Type': 'xxxxxxxx',
      'Status': 'xxxxxxxxx',
      'StatusReason': 'xxxxxxxx',
      'Priority': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'Owner': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'ContactID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'AssetID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'AccountID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'CaseID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}]
```

Comment: `"CaseID" in r` will suffice, no need for `.keys()` in this context

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that JSON data are stored in a variable called *data*.

If you need to extract the whole element you can do something like this:

```
order_list = data["Order"]
for order_item in order_list:
    if "CaseID" in order_item:
        print(order_item)  # print or do whatever you need
```

Please note that using *in order_item* means *in order_item.keys()*. This is done automatically by Python.

if you need to extract the value of *CaseID* key you can do like this:

```
order_list = data["Order"]
for order_item in order_list:
    case_id = order_item.get("CaseID", None)
    if case_id is not None:
        print(case_id)  # print or do whatever you need
```

Comment: There are already two answers proposing list comprehension. Spelling it out in a full blown loop seems redundant. If you'd like to make it more accessible to appeal to those who haven't quite got their head around comprehension, you could at least elaborate and accumulate each qualifying row in some result list.

Comment: We don't know what the user needs to do with this element. Probably this is just a simple reproducible example of the real case scenario.

Comment: I just don't see what this answer adds on top of @deadshot's comment and Hamza's answer. It also happens to be the longest answer so imho it just adds clutter and makes the entire page less readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a pure `pandas` approach:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(x['Order'])
df[df['CaseID'].notna()]
```